# Saxon Prematurely Evalutes xsl:attribute-set

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, saxon, xslt-3.0

This relates to schema-aware validation of inputs into an XSLT transformation using latest Saxon EE 9.8.

My XSLT file contains the following.

A namespace and associated schema defined as such:

```
<xsl:import-schema namespace="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" schema-location="/path/to/some_swbml.xsd"/>
```

A result document conforming to the above schema:

```
<xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$file}" format="swbml-format" validation="strict">
    <SWBML xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" xsl:use-attribute-sets="ir">
        GENERATE SOME MORE XML TO BE VALIDATED BY THE XSD
    </SWBML>
 </xsl:result-document>
```

You will note that the parent tag in the result document `<SWBML>` uses an attrribute set `xsl:use-attribute-sets="ir"`.

The attribute set is defined as per below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:attribute-set name="ir">
        <xsl:attribute name="version">4-2</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is a toy-example, the boilerplate isn't justified above!

This works fine when I use it with:

```
 java net.sf.saxon.Transform -sa -ext:on -it -o:output.xml -xsl:example.xslt
```

This is expected because "-sa" will only check the outputed XML document, as I understand it.

This doesn't work:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -val:lax -ext:on -it -o:output.xml -xsl:example.xslt
```

Giving:

```
FORG0001: Attribute @xsl:use-attribute-sets is not allowed on element <SWBML>
```

**My question is** - shouldn't the validator process the attribute sets before trying validate the `<SWBML>`?  It looks to me like it's complaining that an XSLT instruction is not permitted in the output XML document, which is of course true, but it seems to be checking prematurely.

The resulting XML is valid:

```
<SWBML xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" version="4_2">
```

As demonstrated by transforming with the "-sa" option.

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of XSLT, or a bug in Saxon processing?  It feels like I should be able to do this to me!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce this.

I ran this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  version="3.0">

  <xsl:import-schema namespace="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2">
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2">
      <xs:element name="SWBML">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
              <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:decimal"/>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </xsl:import-schema>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" validation="strict">
      <SWBML xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" xsl:use-attribute-sets="ir">
        GENERATE SOME MORE XML TO BE VALIDATED BY THE XSD
      </SWBML>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:attribute-set name="ir">
      <xsl:attribute name="version">4.2</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>


</xsl:transform>
```

using the command line options:

```
-xsl:test.xsl -sa -val:lax -it -t
```

and it ran fine.

It looks to me as if for some reason you are validating the stylesheet itself. Perhaps the stylesheet uses the construct `document("")` to read its own source code, in which case lax validation will kick in and cause this failure. If that's not the explanation, please provide more detail of exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks vm for the clue - buried elsewhere in the XSLT was a self look-up of the SWBML namespace `<xsl:variable name="fpml-ns" select="namespace-uri(document('')//node()[local-name()='SWBML'])"/>`.

Comment: Just for clarification is there any way around this short of removing the `document('')`?  It looks to me that by design the answer is "no", but was wondering if there is a way of saying "do not validate" for a given document?

Comment: You can use the saxon:doc() function which has a second argument that can be used to set validation (and other) options. But is document('') good practice anyway, it really shouldn't be necessary with XSLT 3.0, and it means the stylesheet can only be executed if the source code is available which limits deployment options.

Comment: To change I replaced document with `<xsl:variable name="fpml-ns" select="'http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2'"/>` then set the SWBML namespace off that.  I replace `<SWBML xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" xsl:use-attribute-sets="ir">` with `<xsl:element name="SWBML" namespace="{$fpml-ns}" use-attribute-sets="ir">`.... this breaks - `Static error at swbBrokerTradeId on line` and then `XTTE1510: Element swbHeader is not permitted in the content model of the complex type Q{http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2}SWBML`. swbHeader  is a child of SWBML, and swbBrokerTradeId a child of swbHeader .

Comment: If I replace `<xsl:element name="SWBML" namespace="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" use-attribute-sets="ir">` with  `<xsl:element name="SWBML" xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" use-attribute-sets="ir">` it works fine.  I'm obviously missing a trick here!

Comment: Sorry, I think this is a supplementary question. Packing supplementary questions into comments isn't good practice; comments are too restricted to present the information clearly. Raise a new question.