# Single definition of a namespace in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a namespace that is used both dynamically and statically.

I'd like to define it only once.

Dynamic use is like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="fpml-ns" select="'http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2'"/>
<xsl:function name="qt:some-function">
    <xsl:param name="pd"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="qt:other-function($fpml-ns, $pd)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

This is ultimately being used to set a `namespace` on an `element` tag, which is then returned as the function result.  The `other-function` can be used with many namespaces, hence it is dynamic.

In the same XSLT file, static use is like this - the namespace only applies to a specific result document within the XSLT:

```
<SWBML xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" xsl:use-attribute-sets="swbml.ir">
```

So the string "http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" appears twice in my XSLT file - and whilst not a disaster I find the duplication suboptimal.

I've tried to make the SWBML element dynamic too, i.e:

```
<element name="SWBML" namespace="${fpml-ns}" use-attribute-sets="swbml.ir">
```

However as per this post: [How can I dynamically set the default namespace declaration of an XSLT transformation's output XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432818/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-default-namespace-declaration-of-an-xslt-transform)

Children do not inherit dynamic namespaces as they would with the static definition.

I have considered the rather ugly workaround of referencing the current document and reading it like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="fpml-ns" select="namespace-uri(document('')//node()[local-name()='SWBML'])"/>
```

This works, but causes problems when trying to do schema-aware valuation of the inputs, as the current document is then validated using the namespace of the result leading to this problem - [Saxon Prematurely Evalutes xsl:attribute-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493231/saxon-prematurely-evalutes-xslattribute-set)

Is there a sensible way to achieve a single defintion of the namespace that I can then reference both statically and dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that comes to mind is to use an XML entity:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY ns "http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2">
]>

....

<SWBML xmlns="&ns;" xsl:use-attribute-sets="swbml.ir">

....

<xsl:variable name="fpml-ns" select="'&ns;'"/>
```

I'm no great fan of XML entities but some people swear by them...